# Create related workitems in Microsoft Team Foundation Server by script or automatically?

Tags: tfs

Is there anyone know a way that you can create related work items to a us/task/bug in Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 by script or automatically with proper field filled?

scenario 1:
when I created a user story, also need to create a bunch of tasks and assigned to different role(Dev, QA, BA etc)

Scenario 2:
When I created a bug, also need to create different tasks with custom title

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

We've done it this way:

1. Create an alert on a new work item, pointing to a web service.
2. The web service now gets all the data for a new work item (you can filter if you want).
3. In the web service you are now able to use the TFS API to create whatever you want.